# Difference between a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Folland Theorem 2.40)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

[image]

In the proof of Theorem 2.40 b), it says the proof follows from Theorem 1.19. But in Theorem 1.19, we have $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. So why does Theorem 2.40 still hold with $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attention**: In the proof of Theorem 2.40 b), it **does not** say the proof follows from Theorem 1.19.

The exact sentence in Folland is : "This proves the first equation in part (a); the second one, and part (b), then follows as in the proofs of Theorem 1.18 and 1.19."

Note that the expression used is "...**follows as in the proofs**...", and it  means the second equation in part (a), and part (b), can be proved in a **similar way** to the proofs of  Theorem 1.18 and 1.19. But it was never implied that Theorem 2.40 b) is a consequence of Theorem 1.19.